# pagination on custom post wp_query

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $loop = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'html5-blank',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'paged'=>$paged
            )
        );
?>
<?php if ($loop->have_posts()): while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>      
 //Loop Code Here..
 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
   <nav>
        <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &raquo;' ); ?>
        <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
    </nav>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

Url on next page as I input result is: www.mywebsite.com/blog/page/2 is WORKING.
But I can't show the pagination links.

Where did it go wrong?

EDIT: Pagination link is showing in `page/2/` but not in the main blog page. 
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you put `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` in the wrong place.. shouldn't it be next or after pagination codes?

something like this

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Right. I put it right after the div nav. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! Isn't it exactly what I told you there was wrong with it?

Answer (score 24):

There are 3 ways that I would suggest for pagination with a custom post wp_query. Unfortunately to this day there isn't a lot of good information about this out there, or at least what is out there is unclear in some cases. Hopefully this helps!

Note, you also did have the wp_reset_postdata() in the wrong place, but even still more is needed to get it to work correctly.

### Option 1 - use max_num_pages variable

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'post_type' => 'cpt_type'
    );
    $cpt_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ($cpt_query->have_posts()) : while ($cpt_query->have_posts()) : $cpt_query->the_post(); ?>

    //Loop Code Here...

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $cpt_query->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
        <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $cpt_query->max_num_pages) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You'll see above, a slightly different format for `previous_posts_link` and `next_posts_link` which now access the `max_num_pages` variable. Be sure to use your own query variable name when accessing `max_num_pages`. Notice I use $cpt_query since that is the variable for my query example.

### Option 2 - temporarily use the $wp_query variable for your loop query

This is what a lot of folks recommend, but be careful to asign the $wp_query variable to a temp variable and re-assign it or you will run in to all kinds of troubles. Which is why I recommend Option #1. As noted on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/), you can do something like this:

```
<?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=6&post_type=news'.'&paged='.$paged); 

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

  <!-- LOOP: Usual Post Template Stuff Here-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</nav>

<?php 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

### Option 3 - use WP-pagenavi plugin

Just as another option what you can do instead is use the [WP-pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin, and setup your query as in Option #1. But make one change in the code, remove everything within the  element and replace with this function, once you have installed the plugin. So you'll end with:

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $cpt_query ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered very adequately by @Trevor but I needed to implement numbered pagination, and there was a bit more research to do. I hope my code helps others implement numbered pagination.

```php
    <div class="frontpage-posts">
        <?php
        if (get_query_var('paged')) {
          $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
          $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {
          $paged = 1;
        }
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=12&paged=' . $paged);
        if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
          while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
            echo the_title();
          endwhile; ?>
          <nav>
            <?php
            the_posts_pagination(array(
              'mid_size'  => 2,
              'prev_text' => __('Back', 'textdomain'),
              'next_text' => __('Onward', 'textdomain'),
            ));
            ?>
          </nav>
        <?php
          $wp_query = null;
          $wp_query = $temp;
          wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
        ?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'wp-rest-api-log',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged'         => $paged,
    'orderby'       => 'date',
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($loop->have_posts()) :
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
      echo the_title();
    endwhile;
    
    echo "<nav class=\"sw-pagination\">";
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
    ) );
    echo "</nav>";
endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php    
add_shortcode('show_all_news', 'show_all_news');
    function show_all_news($atts) {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $limit = 4;
        $offset = ( $limit * $paged ) - $limit;
        $atts['pages'] = $paged; 
        $atts['post-type'] = 'your_custom_post_type'; 
        $atts['orderby'] = 'date'; 
        $atts['order'] = 'DESC';
        $atts['offset'] = $offset; 
        $atts['posts_per_page'] = $limit; 
        $atts['caller_get_posts'] = 1; 

        $result = new WP_Query($atts);
        echo '<div class="news-cont">';  
        if($result->have_posts())
        {
            while ($result->have_posts()) : $result->the_post(); 
                echo '<div class="bg-white news-block">'; 
                echo '<em class="date">'. get_the_date().'</em>' ?>

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php 
                echo "<p>";
                the_excerpt(); 
                echo "</p>";
                echo '</div>';
            endwhile;

            ?>
                <ul class="pagination" style="width:100%;">
                    <li id="previous-posts" style="float:left">
                        <?php previous_posts_link( '<< Vorige Pagina', $result->max_num_pages ); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li id="next-posts" style="float:right">
                        <?php next_posts_link( 'Volgende Pagina >>', $result->max_num_pages ); ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php 

        }
        echo '</div>'; 
        wp_reset_query();
    }
```

Comment: suraj sing, Would you like to add some details that you addressed in the answer by updating it?

Comment: This is a working code Just change post type........... add your custom post type and add this code in functions.php and do_shortcode('shortcodename '); in category listing page where you needed pagination...... this will work

Comment: @surajsingh, Involving short code is something not recommended or necessary at all in this situation. Also, you did not give any information about explaining your solution. Thank you.