# Woocommerce custom products list pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have code like this for fetching and displaying products in woocommerce:

```
{
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 30
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
//display results here;
endwhile;
}
```

The problem is while the code displays 30 products at a time as specified, it does not add page links so other products could be viewed, is there a way to do this or am I missing somethin?

Comment: Hi, Your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <ul class="products">
        <?php
        global $paged;

            $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'paged' => $paged


                );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                endwhile;
            } else {
                echo __( 'No products found' );
            }
        ?>


    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
            <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul><!--/.products-->
```

Reference : [Pagination in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216915/pagination-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check below code? i hope this code is work for you.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        //display results here;
    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }    
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```