# How can I show 3 products per page and add numbered pagination?

Tags: php, woocommerce, pagination

I am trying to use the following code to show 3 products and add pagination to it:

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
    global $paged;

        $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'paged' => $paged

            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
    ?>

    <nav class="clearfix">
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
            <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();

do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); ?>
```

How can I show 3 products per page and add numbered pagination?

Comment: I guess use `posts_per_page` instead of `per_page` option [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304892/woocommerce-custom-products-list-pagination)

Comment: That helped a bit, but how can I add numbered pagination to it?