# adding pagination to a custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, pagination, custom-post-type, wordpress

I am facing a little issue while adding pagination to a custom post type which I've created inside Wordpress. The pagination links are appearing on the template where I've all the posts, inside the custom post type, listed but when I click on the link to view Older posts, it opens the second page but the same posts from the first page are displayed there. Moreover, on the second page, the 'Older posts' link doesn't update to '../page/3', instead it stays '../page/2'. I followed the steps specified here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18325002/2115001) and modified my code according to the information listed under 'Option 2'. Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
<?php

    $temp = $wp_query;

    $wp_query = null;

    $wp_query = new WP_Query();

    $wp_query->query('showposts=3&post_type=medals'.'&paged='.$paged);

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

    // loops code here

    endwhile;

    echo '<nav>';

    echo previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer');

    echo next_posts_link('Older &raquo;');

    echo '</nav>';

    $wp_query = null;

    $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset

?>
```

Do I need to add some code to the functions.php file in order for this to function properly or there's something wrong in my original code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
$paged = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,
'paged'=> $paged,
'post_type' => 'medals');

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

// loops code here

endwhile;

global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999;

echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
'next_text' => __('Next »'),
));
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work as well. The pagination links do not point to a sub-page.

Comment: Replace the 4th line with below line and This will generate numeric pagination.

$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=3&post_type=medals&paged='.$paged);

Comment: I've replaced the code but if you check the website now, you'll see that all the pagination links are pointed towards the homepage. I believe we're close but there seems to be some glitch.

Comment: Ok, Move global $wp_query; just after the endwhile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60889/discussion-between-fahad-hasan-and-user2014).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
  $type = 'portfolio';
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
  );
  $temp = $wp_query;  // assign original query to temp variable for later use
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  wp_query->query($args);
?>
```

then put your permalinks to the default structure and back to how the structure was.

Comment: the website fails to load when I replace my code with your code. I am replacing the following code with your code:

     $temp = $wp_query;

     $wp_query = null;

     $wp_query = new WP_Query();

     $wp_query->query('showposts=3&post_type=medals'.'&paged='.$paged);

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>              
 <article class="">
           <div class="">
            <h4><?php the_time( 'm' ); ?></h4>
            <h4><?php the_time( 'd' ); ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</article>               

 <?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>

<?php
  global $wp_query;

  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
//echo  esc_url( get_pagenum_link());
   echo paginate_links( array(
      'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'type'=>'list',
    'prev_text'    => __('<'),
    'next_text'    => __('>'),
  ) );
?>
```

Hope it will work for you.