# Numbered paginated links not displaying

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am trying to display a numbered paginated link at the bottom of my blog but they don't appear to work using the suggested method as stated on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

I have a wp query which should fetch 5 posts at a time then display another page. I have 10 posts set so should definitely be seeing the pagination controls

```
<?php

    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'post_type' => 'post' ,
        'orderby' => 'date',
      'order'   => 'DESC',
      'paged' => ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1
    );

    $postslist = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<div class="row section blog-posts">

    <?php while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="blog-post">

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <div class="page-controls">
        <?php echo paginate_links( 
                array(
                    'base'               => '%_%',
                    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
                    'total'              => 1,
                    'current'            => 0,
                    'show_all'           => false,
                    'end_size'           => 1,
                    'mid_size'           => 2,
                    'prev_next'          => true,
                    'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
                    'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
                    'type'               => 'plain',
                    'add_args'           => false,
                    'add_fragment'       => '',
                    'before_page_number' => '',
                    'after_page_number'  => ''
                ) 
            ); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pagination on custom post wp\_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595709/pagination-on-custom-post-wp-query)

Comment: try increase `total` . and i don't see any reason why u need `wp_reset_postdata()` there

Comment: @cjmling that did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @Stretch0 I posted as answer below. Can you accept it if it solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As based in comment above. Increasing `total` param in `paginate_links` to be more than 1 fixed the issue.