# How can I paginate foreach loop in wp?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, pagination

I have a `foreach loop` which shows items from my custom wordpress database table. 
It works good but I want to limit this loop as 10 posts per page and make it paged.
I want to learn the code mechanism, so can you please explain me how can I do this?

**my code summary is:**

```
<?php global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_messages" );
    foreach ( $results as $print ) { ?>

    <!-- loop -->
    from: <?php $print->sender_user; ?>
    message: <?php $print->message; ?>
    <!-- loop -->

    <?php } //foreach ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pagination on custom post wp\_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595709/pagination-on-custom-post-wp-query)

Comment: How can I identify the "wp_messages" table in wp_query ?

Comment: wp_messages is not a core WordPress table.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather a PHP thing, a WordPress solution wouldn't be available as it is a separate database table. You can search for a PHP pagination tutorial for a solution.

You need to fetch the data using `limit` query in sql, in the first page

```
SELECT * FROM wp_messages limit 0,10
```

and in next page

```
SELECT * FROM wp_messages limit 11,20
```