# How can I show my index page posts with post meta?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I try to show my posts in my index page with post meta for this reason I make a wp query like this:

```
 <?php $recent = new WP_Query(
        array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_key' => 'post-filter-select',
        'meta_value' => 'music'));

 while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
```

It's great and work but for pagination I have big problem! It don't work!
may I customize my index page query? How can I do this customization with keeping my pagination work ?

Comment: If you want to modify the original WP query, then you can use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/)  hook. (You need to be careful to identify the right query though.)

Comment: Check it, please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595709/pagination-on-custom-post-wp-query

Answer (score 1):

Quick example:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_value' => 'music'
);
$recent = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if ($recent->have_posts()) : while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>

    // loop

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $recent->max_num_pages) ?></li>
        <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $recent->max_num_pages) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Hope help you.