# Paginate custom SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm really new to WordPress backend. Here I'm trying to pass variables through $_POST and get results according to those variables from my database. Everything is working fine, the only problem I'm facing is that I'm getting 80 to 90 results and I want to paginate this thing.
I've tried doing it by bypassing the page variable in the URL, but I think $_POST variables are not passing on page 2.
I'm adding the code below.

```html
<?php
$graphic = $_POST["graphics"];
$mem = $_POST["memo"];
$opsys = $_POST["osys"];
$cpuu = $_POST["cpu"];
$hddd = $_POST["hdd"];
?>
<?php  
$rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game_list WHERE game_ram <= $mem AND game_card <= $graphic AND game_hdd <= $hddd AND game_os <= $opsys AND game_cpu <= $cpuu ");
?> 
<p>
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $row;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM game_list where game_ram <= $mem AND game_card <= $graphic AND game_hdd <= $hddd AND game_os <= $opsys AND game_cpu <= $cpuu order by release_date desc");

?>

<div>


<div style="padding:7px;"><h3> We found <font style="color:blue;"><?php echo $rowcount; ?></font> Results</h3><br><a href="https://wgod7.com/game-search-page/">Reset Parameters/Search Again</a></div>

<?php
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo "<div class=\"column\" style=\"width:100%;min-height: fit-content;padding:5px; margin:3px;border: 1px solid;border-radius: 15px; float: left;\">
<div class=\"column\" style=\"width:25%; float: left;\">
<img src=\"";
echo $row->game_icon;
echo "\" style=\"height: 138px;width:98px;\">
</div>
<div class=\"column\" style=\"padding:5px;width:75%; float: left;\"><a href=\"";
echo $row->game_link;
echo "\"><b>";  
echo $row->game_name;
echo "</a></b><hr> <b>WGod7 Game Score : </b>";
echo $row->metacritic_score;
echo "<br><b>Release Date : </b>";
echo $row->release_date;
echo "<span style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\""; echo $row->game_link; echo"\">Read More...</a></span>";
echo "</div></div>";    
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound/executed queries

Comment: Its worth looking at Wp_Query https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ class. WordPress makes it very easy to make paginations with WP_Query.  This should help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595709/pagination-on-custom-post-wp-query 

And do take @Strawberry comment seriously and read about sql_injection. It will make your website secure.